# I cant upload my image in MultipartBody.Part type to retrofit in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

This code is from the fragment this works without the multipartbody.part in retrofit but isnot working when this multipartbody.part data is added

```
 fun converToBitmap(filename:String,bitmapdata:ByteArray
  ,image2:MutableLiveData<MultipartBody.Part>) 
{
   val f = File(requireActivity().cacheDir, filename)
   f.createNewFile()

   var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
   try {
       fos = FileOutputStream(f)
   } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
       e.printStackTrace()
   }
   try {
       fos?.write(bitmapdata)
       fos?.flush()
       fos?.close()
   } catch (e: IOException) {
       e.printStackTrace()
   }
   val reqFile: RequestBody = RequestBody.create("image/jpg".toMediaTypeOrNull(), f)
   val body: MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", f.name, reqFile)
   image2.value = body

 }
```

the code below is the code for api service in retrofit and the above code which is in the fragment and the code works without multipart data image or when this multipartbody.part is null

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("addlandlist")
suspend fun addlandlist(@Field("username") username:String?,
                        @Part ("img1")img1: MultipartBody.Part?,
                        @Part ("img2")img2: MultipartBody.Part?,
                        @Part ("img3")img3: MultipartBody.Part?,
                        @Field("google_map") google_map:String?,
                        @Field("place_name") place_name:String?,
                        @Field("village") village:String?,
                        @Field("hb_taluk") hb_taluk:String?,
                        @Field("properties_land") properties_land:String?,
                        @Field("other_spec") other_spec:String?,
                        @Field("land_type") land_type:String?,
                        @Field("leagal_issues") leagal_issues:String?,
                        @Field("contact_num") contact_num:String?,
                        @Field("address") address:String?,
                        @Field("price") price:String?): DataValues
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using [Multipart](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Multipart.html) & [FormUrlEncoded](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/FormUrlEncoded.html) together. Don't mix Multipart & FormUrlEncoded together. By annotating `@Mutipart` you are specifying `Content-Type` as `multipart/form-data` and when you annotate `@FormUrlEncoded` setting `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. As you're using both, which is conflicting to each other. Use @Multipart only.

And additionally you seems to be using some of the DEPRECATED method `RequestBody.create(...)` to create the File `RequestBody`. Instead you can use `File.asRequestBody()` to create File RequestBody & `String.toRequestBody()` to create String RequestBody.

Here is a rough example, you can use Only Multipart as follow

```
//Service
@Multipart
@POST("addlandlist")
suspend fun addlandlist(
    @PartMap params: Map<String, RequestBody>,
    @Part img1: MultipartBody.Part
)
```

Here is how you can add text params in PartMap. And create file and string RequestBody & Part.

```
val file1 = File("") // just for example I'm initializing File with "" path

val params = HashMap<String, RequestBody>()

params["username"] = "text/text".toRequestBody()
params["google_map"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["place_name"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["village"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["hb_taluk"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["properties_land"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["other_spec"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["land_type"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["leagal_issues"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["contact_num"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["address"] = "".toRequestBody()
params["price"] = "".toRequestBody()


val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("img1", file1.name, reqFile1)

apiService.addlandlist(params, filePart)
```

## Other Useful Links

[Multiple Parts with @PartMap](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap)

[Upload Files With Retrofit 2](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server)